# XtraReport calculated field not working, always display zero

Tags: devexpress, calculated-field, xtrareport

I have created a summary calculated field **sumMyField** with Type **Int32**, the expression is **Sum([MyField])**, the column values are not 0, my others calculated fields in other reports are working correctly, but in this report the calculated field is always zero. I think it is relative to something like "cache". I cannot deleted the report and re-create it, as this takes too long to re-design[image]

Comment: How is this report created, via code or through the report designer? The issue will not be due to cache, it will be due to the Summary expression of the field being incorrect somewhere along the line.

Comment: No, I deleted the cell, recreate the cell and drag the field from field explorer and everything run smooth

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

Delete the cell, recreate it and recreate the field to it. The calculated expression is correct!